# Obtain words in a cell with a vowel at a specific position in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following columns
`affix, word,  sense and meaning`. Now if I want to obtain all the entries in the column `word`, whose fourth charcter from last is `a`.

The following snippet provides me the answer

```
pd[(pd['affix'] == 'man') & (pd['word'].str[-4] == 'a' )  ]
```

The output is

```
        affix   word        sense                  meaning
9900    man     cameraman   who     # somebody who operates a [[movie]] [[camera]]...
9901    man     cameraman   who     # {{l|en|cameraman}} {{gloss|somebody who oper...
```

But if i want to cobtain the entries whose 4th character from last is a vowel, the following code snippet does not work. Any help would be helpful to achieve the results

```
  pd[(pd['affix'] == 'man') & (pd['word'].str[-4] in ['a','e','i','o','u'] )  ]
```

The error shown is

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: use `isin`: `pd['word'].str[-4].isin(['a','e','i','o','u']) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
pd[(pd['affix'] == 'man') & (pd['word'].str[-4].isin(['a','e','i','o','u']))]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can match with [`str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

```
pd[(pd['affix'] == 'man') & pd.str.match('.*[aeiou].{3}$')
```

`'.*[aeiou].{3}$'` is a regular expression that says to:

- `'.*'` match anything any number of times
- `'[aeiou]'` followed by a single character from the list between brackets
- `'.{3}$'` followed by any 3 characters then followed by the end of the string.